# Angular CLI build split scripts file

Tags: javascript, angular, split, configuration, command-line-interface

I have configuration of Angular CLI

```
 ...
"prefix": "app",
"styles": [
        "styles.css",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss"
      ],
"scripts": [
        "./data/main-categories.js",
        "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
 ],
...
```

After build, my all scripts are in one Javascript file by name scripts.js.

I want to split scripts to two Javascript files:

```
data.js for ->./data/main-categories.js
scripts.js ->./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js and others
```

It is possible in Angular CLI?

Comment: Can you add motive behind doing that , it might help sometimes

Comment: I want to have split files, because data file is often changed and it cause that will must be downloaded from server. I don't want download others scripts again e.g. bootstrap, because are cached in browser .

Comment: In that case you can copy them to assets and include in the HTML seperately . Dont include them in `angularcli.json`

Comment: Yes, this is option, but I have several  data files e.g. main-categories.js, subcategories.js, ...  I want to build all data files to one with hash and automatic add to index file. Thank you

Comment: Understood. Good question. May be we can do that with webpack easily.

Comment: Another option is to eject cli using `ng eject` and configure bundles the way you want